# Is it possible to load in all sets in the context under EF?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In my view model I have the following constructor.

```
public ViewModel()
{
  Data data = new Data();

  data.Set<Stuff>().Load();
  data.Set<Things>().Load();
  ...

  Stuff = data.Set<Stuff>().Local;
  Things = data.Set<Things>().Local;
  ...
}
```

I understand that call to *Local* property is inevitable, since the public properties of the view model are called different names and those are hard-coded. However, since the list is rather extensive, I wonder if there's a way to at least shorten the constructor by making the loading being carried out in one, single command.

I'm hoping for something like this.

```
public ViewModel()
{
  ...
  data.AllSets.Load();
  ...
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure but looks like you can disable lazy loading via `data.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;` then try accessing the entities via the exposed properties of `data`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use reflection and iterate over all members of your DB-Context class and verify whether a member is a generic type of `DbSet<>` or not. If this is true, you can execute `Load()`.

I would recommend to implement said approach in a separate `DbContext` derived class, such as `MyDbContext : DbConbtext`. Maybe later I can provide some example.

**Here the example**:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
 {
     /// <summary>
     /// Execute the 'Load' method for every DbSet<> property in the current DbContext
     /// </summary>
     public void LoadAll()
     {
         // Get all properties which should be loaded
         var propreties = typeof(FrameworkDbContext).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
             .Where(Item => Item.PropertyType.IsGenericType && Item.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(DbSet<>)).ToList();

         // Get method which will be exeecuted for every property (Extension method)
         var loadMethod = typeof(QueryableExtensions)
                              .GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public)
                              .Where(mi => mi.Name == "Load").FirstOrDefault(); 


         if (loadMethod != null)
         {
             foreach (var property in propreties)
             {
                 var value = property.GetValue(this);

                 // Execute load method
                 loadMethod.Invoke(value, new object[] { value });
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: There's a +1 waiting if you do provide an example (for future readers).

Comment: @KonradViltersten hope this helps. The extension method is a little bit confusing maybe...